# How can I set AWS credentials in AWS PowerShell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

I just downloaded the latest version of AWS Powershell and tried this: Before I don't remember any problem. Now I am getting this error message:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey xxxxxxxx -SecretKey xxxxxxx -StoreAs xxxx
Set-AWSCredentials : The term 'Set-AWSCredentials' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey xxxxxxx -SecretKey xxxxx
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AWSCredentials:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Has some syntax changed again :-(

Thanks

Comment: you probably have to import the aws module using `Import-Module`

Comment: I have never imported any module before. Can you give me some more details. Note that I just downloaded and installed the AWS powershell and I am using the AWS powershell.  Thanks

Comment: If you have just installed AWS toolkit, you may try closing the current powershell window and re-open it (assuming it was already open before the installation.)

Comment: @Alan Do you know what version of AWS PowerShell you were using previously?

Comment: Last time I used AWS PowerShell was about two months ago and it was the latest then.  All I would like to do is to set the credentials :-(  I tried it on two machines now.  My experiences with AWS powershell have not been so great so far.  Wish I did not have to say that but just my experience.

Comment: I should add both are fresh installs on Windows 10.  I had hoped that after installing and opening I would not see problems like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools install to a folder structure compliant with the auto-import support in PowerShell version 3 or higher, so `Import-Module` should not be needed.

It does however require that the `PSModulePath` update the installer performs takes effect, and we've noticed that on some systems you need to reboot after install.

Looking at `PSModulePath` you should see something like this (excuse wrapping):

```
PS C:\> ls env:PSModulePath | fl

Name  : PSModulePath
Value : C:\Users\userid\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program
        Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\
```

If so, try restarting your machine and then open a shell prompt and see if `Set-AWSCredentials` becomes available. If not, report back and we'll try and repro.

Answer (score -1):

try this two options:

1. As @steve-roberts said, restart pc (didn't work for me)
2. Install the latest Power shell version (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1)

Best,